# How can I set the time for a query to be executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have this queries:

```
create view view_A (
select * from tbl1
)
```

ended?

do this:

```
select * into table_A from view_A
```

ended?

do this:

```
create view view_B as 
(
select a,b,c from table_A

)
```

ended?

do this:

```
select * into table_B from view_B
```

Is there any option to set the excution's in this way? 
Suppose I don't know how much time I will need for each query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using MS SQL Server.

Statements such as CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a batch. In order to separate batches, you will need to use the keyword GO;

The queries will be executed synchronously so there is no need for you to start query 2 once query 1 has completed.

```
CREATE VIEW view_A as 
(
select [a] = 1234, [b] = 5678, [c] = 0987
);
GO
select * into table_A from view_A;
GO
create view view_B as 
(
select a,b,c from table_A
);
GO
select * into table_B from view_B
```

Comment: what is the purpose of [a] and [b] and [c]? what are they? thank's!

Comment: Replace those with your select statement
select * from tbl1

Answer (score -1):

put all the queries in a .sql file and execute it from the command line

Eg:
mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabase < text_file.sql

Comment: Can you explain more? I didn't understand the last sentence.